# HTML Javascript String linking

Tags: javascript, html

How can I link a string in a HTML page to another HTML page with JAVASCRIPT? Do i have to create a js file to do this?

For example:- there is a **js string1** in page 1 and **js string2** in page2 and each of them hava a link to go to page 3. Think there is a "heading" in page 3. I want to change this "heading" as **js string1** when i access page 3 by page1.

*Likewise I want to change this "heading" as **js string2** when i access page 3 by page2.*

What is the JavaScript code that I have to use to get this outputs?

Comment: Errr... it is not clear what you want to accomplish. Could you show us the small piece of your code, where you want to 'link a string to another page'?

Comment: Yes, can create a js file. make a "ID" of string and on click of string you can call this function "window.location.href= http //www.abc.com"

Comment: Please now dont tell you cant understand what im saying :o

Answer (score 0):

No, if you can't do something like 
    `<link rel="text/html" href="another.html">`

but you GET another page using java-script, 
see http://api.jquery.com/get to use it via jQuery

but if you are just trying to embed a page inside another page you can use `<iframe>`

iframe will include another page inside your current page as a frame
`<iframe src="another.html"></iframe>` this might just fix your purpose

Also remember this is not the best method to join or include 2 pages.
There are good methods if you are using a back end language too with the help of includes and stuff and I highly recommend you to study them